# Java like function getLeastSignificantBits() & getMostSignificantBits in Swift?

Tags: swift, uuid, foundation

I would like to know a function/method to get LeastSignificantBits & MostSignificantBits in Swift for the Foundation.UUID().uuidstring which is a randomly generated Unique Universal Identifier and also know the opposite, to create a Foundation.UUID() from LeastSignificantBits & MostSignificantBits

Answer (score 0):

This is the String extension to get LeastSignificantBits & MostSignificantBits from an existing UUID().uuidstring (ex: "6C5E3281-2471-4C39-9CE6-A882B16A28FE")

```
extension String {
    func getUUIDMostSigBit() -> Int64 {
        let components = self.split(separator: "-")
        var mostSigBits = Int64(components[0], radix: 16)!
        mostSigBits <<= 16
        let c1 = Int64(components[1], radix: 16)!
        mostSigBits |= c1
        mostSigBits <<= 16
        let c2 = Int64(components[2], radix: 16)!
        mostSigBits |= c2
        return mostSigBits
    }
    
    func getUUIDLeastSigBit() -> Int64 {
        let components = self.split(separator: "-")
        var leastSigBits = Int64(components[3], radix: 16)!
        leastSigBits <<= 48
        let c4 = Int64(components[4], radix: 16)!
        leastSigBits |= c4
        return leastSigBits
    }
}
```

Below is the Foundation.UUID extension to create a UUID() if you already have the LeastSignificantBits & MostSignificantBits.

```
    extension Foundation.UUID {
    
    init(mostSigBits: Int64, leastSigBits: Int64) {
        var mostSigBits = mostSigBits
        var leastSigBits = leastSigBits
        let mostData = Data(bytes: &mostSigBits, count: MemoryLayout<Int64>.size)
        let leastData = Data(bytes: &leastSigBits, count: MemoryLayout<Int64>.size)
        let bytes = [UInt8](mostData) + [UInt8](leastData)
        let tuple: uuid_t = (bytes[7], bytes[6], bytes[5], bytes[4],
                             bytes[3], bytes[2], bytes[1], bytes[0],
                             bytes[15], bytes[14], bytes[13], bytes[12],
                             bytes[11], bytes[10], bytes[9], bytes[8])
        self.init(uuid: tuple)
    }
}
```

How to use then interchangeable :

```
let uuidString: String = Foundation.UUID().uuidstring // "6C5E3281-2471-4C39-9CE6-A882B16A28FE"
let msb: Int64 = uuid.getUUIDMostSigBit() // 7808734334150593593
let lsb: Int64 = uuid.getUUIDLeastSigBit() // -7140834879873603330
let uuid: Foundation.UUID() = Foundation.UUID(mostSigBits: msb, leastSigBits: lsb) // Foundation.UUID().uuidstring = "6C5E3281-2471-4C39-9CE6-A882B16A28FE"
```